# Covariance of two Random Variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, covariance

Suppose $r \geq 1$ distinct books are distributed at random among
$n \geq 3$ children.

(a) For each $j \in {0, 1, 2, . . . , r}$, compute the probability that
the first child gets exactly $j$ books.

(b) Let $X$ be the number of children who do not get any book,
and $Y$ be the number of children who get exactly one book.
Show that $$Cov(X, Y)=\frac{r(n-1)(n-2)^{r-1}}{n^{r-1}}-\frac{r(n-1)^{2r-1}}{n^{2r-2}}$$

For part (a) we can view the distribution of books as independent Bernoulli trials such that for each student, the probability of getting the book equals $\frac{1}{n}$ and so the probability that the first child gets exactly $j$ books equals ${r \choose j} (\frac{1}{n})^j(\frac{n-1}{n})^{r-j}$.

For part (b) define $X_{ij}=1$, if the ith student gets the jth book and otherwise zero. Then we have $$X=\sum^n_{i=1}\mathbf{1}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{ij}=0), Y=\sum^n_{i=1}\mathbf{1}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{ij}=1)$$. So, $$Cov(X, Y)=\sum^n_{p=1}\sum^n_{q=1}Cov(\mathbf{1}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{pj}=1), \mathbf{1}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{qj}=0))\\ =\sum^n_{p=1}\sum^n_{q=1}E[\mathbf{1}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{pj}=1)\mathbf{1}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{qj}=0)]-E[\mathbf{1}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{pj}=1)]E[\mathbf{1}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{qj}=0)] \\ =\sum^n_{p=1}\sum^n_{q=1}\mathbb{P}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{pj}=1, \sum^r_{j=1}X_{qj}=0)-\mathbb{P}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{pj}=1)\mathbb{P}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{qj}=0) \\ =\sum^n_{p=1}\sum^n_{q=1}\mathbb{P}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{pj}=1|\sum^r_{j=1}X_{qj}=0)\mathbb{P}(\sum^r_{j=1}X_{qj}=0)-\frac{r(n-1)^{2r-1}}{n^{2r}}  \\ =\sum^n_{p=1}\sum^n_{q=1}{r\choose1}\frac{1}{n-1}(\frac{n-2}{n-1})^{r-1}(\frac{n-1}{n})^r-\frac{r(n-1)^{2r-1}}{n^{2r}}  \\ =\frac{r(n-2)^{r-1}}{n^{r-2}}-\frac{r(n-1)^{2r-1}}{n^{2r-2}}$$.

I want to know where I am getting wrong?

Comment: I have edited my post, now can you please tell me the error in the answer

Comment: I cannot follow everything you have done, but you would have the desired answer if your penultimate line did not have $\frac1{n-1}$.  Where does it come from?

Comment: Given that the qth student gets no book the probability that the pth student gets the jth book equals $\frac{1}{n-1}$ for all $j=1,2,....r$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note on notation: the quantity $\sum_{j=1}^r X_{pj}$ (the number of books child p receives) appears a lot in your argument. I suggest giving this a more concise name. I'll call it $S_p$.

Everything is correct until the penultimate line. Your expression for $\mathbb P(S_p=1,S_q=0)$ is only correct when $p \neq q$.